# Getting the difference of the value of two rows which have the same value in another row

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following table:

```
(table from a previous query)
count(method)    top_url                          Tor

4                http://check.torproject.org      Tor
4                http://check.torproject.org      NoTor
5                http://thebay.ca                 Tor
119              http://thebay.ca                 NoTor
10               http://test.com                  Tor
5                http://test.com                  NoTor
```

I  would like to get the difference between each rows from the same top_url. And if possible, I would like to get the absolute value (remove  the minus sign if there is one).

The output of  the previous table  would be:

```
Diff     top_url

0        http://check.torproject.org
114      http://thebay.ca
5        http://test.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use use `abs()` with conditional aggregation:

```
select top_url,
  abs(max(case when tor = 'Tor' then methodcount else 0 end) - 
      max(case when tor = 'NoTor' then methodcount else 0 end))
from yourresults
group by top_url;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/7dc50/3)